# If $Y$ is determined by and independent of $X$ then $Y$ is deterministic

Tags: probability-theory

I'm working on the following exercise:

> Let $X,Y$ be random variables.  Show that if $Y$ is simultaneously determined by $X$ and independent of $X$ then $Y$ is deterministic.

Here $Y$ is said to be deterministic if $Y = \text{const.}$,  $Y$ is said to be determined by $X$ if $Y = f(X)$ for some measurable function $f$, and $X$ and $Y$ are said to be independent if

$$
P(X \in E \wedge Y \in F) = P(X \in E) P(Y \in F)
$$

for all measurable sets $E,F$ in the respective ranges of $X$ and $Y$.

---

I am having a hard time figuring out why the following situation is not a counterexample to the claim:

Let $\Omega = \{0,1\}$ with measure $P$ defined by $P(\{0\}) = 0$, $P(\{1\}) = P(\{0,1\}) = 1$ and let $X,Y : \Omega \to \Omega$ both be equal to the identity map.

The random variable $Y$ is clearly determined by $X$ since $Y = X$, and I claim that $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

To start, for $E \subseteq \Omega$ we have

$$
P(X \in E) = P(Y \in E) = P(E) = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if } 1 \in E, \\ 0 & \text{otherwise.} \end{cases}
$$

Then we calculate

$$
\begin{align}
& P(X = 0 \wedge Y = 0) = P(X = 0) = 0 \\
&\hspace{2cm} = P(X = 0) P(Y = 0), \\
& \\
& P(X = 0 \wedge Y = 1) = P(\emptyset) = 0 \\
&\hspace{2cm} = P(X = 0) P(Y = 1), \\
& \\
& P(X = 0 \wedge Y \in \{0,1\}) = P(X = 0) = 0 \\
&\hspace{2cm} = P(X = 0) P(Y \in \{0,1\}), \\
& \\
& P(X = 1 \wedge Y = 1) = P(X = 1) = 1 \\
&\hspace{2cm} = P(X = 1) P(Y = 1), \\
& \\
& P(X = 1 \wedge Y \in \{0,1\}) = P(X = 1) = 1 \\
&\hspace{2cm} = P(X = 1) P(Y \in \{0,1\}),
\end{align}
$$

and the rest of the possibilities by symmetry.

Thus $P(X \in E \wedge Y \in F) = P(X \in E) P(Y \in F)$ for all $E,F \subseteq \Omega$, and hence $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

Comment: Hint: Your example is of $X$ being deterministic.

Comment: ...And Y, and every other random variable defined on this probability space.

Comment: @GrahamKemp, Why is $X$ deterministic?  $X(0) \neq X(1)$, so it's non-constant.

Comment: @AntonioVargas If $\;\mathsf P(X\in\{1\})=1\,$ , then $X=1\text{ a.s.}$ .

Comment: @GrahamKemp, The book I'm reading (Tao's *Topics in Random Matrix Theory*) is using the definition that a r.v. $X$ is deterministic if $X = a$ (for some $a$) *surely*, not almost surely.  Is this not the norm?

Comment: @Did, I think we are using different definitions of deterministic.  For you, is a r.v. deterministic if $X = a$ for some $a$ a.s.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $X$ is not a constant r.v. Independence of $X$ and $Y$ implies the for any Borel measurable sets $A_1,A_2$

$$\mathbb{P}\{X\in f^{-1}(A_1)\bigcap A_2\}=\mathbb{P}\{X\in f^{-1}(A_1)\}\mathbb{P}\{X\in A_2\}$$

In particular, this holds for sets of the form $A, f^{-1}(A)$ so that

$$\mathbb{P}\{f(X)\in A\}=\left[\mathbb{P}\{f(X)\in A\}\right]^2$$

Hence, for any Borel measurable set $A$, $\mathbb{P}\{f(X)\in A\}=0$ or $1$ which shows that $Y=f(X)$ must be a constant r.v.

Comment: Thanks for the answer d.k.o., but the situation I outlined in my question is a counterexample to your claim that $\mathbb P\{f(X) \in A\} = 0$ or $1$ implies $f(X)$ is constant.

Comment: @AntonioVargas: The question is how do you define deterministic r.v. I can guess that a suitable definition would be $P$-a.s. constant for any probability measure $P$ defined on $(\Omega,\mathcal{F})$

Comment: Assuming that definition, does your argument lead to the conclusion?  It needs to be shown that $P(f(X) = c) = 1$ for some $c$.  I've tried to proceed by way of contradiction, so assuming $P(f(X) = c) = 0$ for all $c$.  From this it follows that $P(f(X) \in A) = 0$ for all countable sets $A$, but I can't see how to reach a contradiction from here.  After all, the map defined by $\mu(E) = 0$ if $E$ is countable and $1$ if $E$ is uncountable is a valid measure.

Comment: @AntonioVargas I'm not sure that I'm following you... Nevertheless, $\mathbb{P}\{f(X)\in A\}=0$ or $1$ holds for any Borel measurable set. In particular, this holds for sets of the form $(-\infty,z]$ (we are talking about real random variable $Y:\Omega\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$). Then since $F_Y(z)=\mathbb{P}\{Y\le z\}$ is non-decreasing in $z$ and $F_Y(-\infty)=0\text{, and }F_Y(\infty)=1$ there must be some $c$ s.t. $\mathbb{P}\{f(X)=c\}=F_Y(c)-F_Y(c-)=1$.